# Is there an "Open Source" repository for Sketchup woodworking plans?

Tags: planning

Does anyone know of a good repository for woodworking plans in Sketchup format? I'm looking for something like Github, but for woodworking.

Currently I just do searches for a specific plans in Google, but it seems logical that someone has created an "Open Source" type community for plans where one could find plans and contribute their own.

Comment: [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com) is probably a better model. Github isn't a repository, it's a service that hosts repositories. AFAIK each Sketchup document is pretty much self-contained, so you just want a service that hosts lots of those files.

Comment: SketchUp itself also has a wide variety of free models available within its store. Many of them are useful products for woodworkers (like drawer pulls), some of them are a bit more _architectural_ (like toilets).